# Polarization of conduction and valence bands

Tags: solid-state-physics, polarization, crystals, electronic-band-theory

As title, this is something that I read in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.00172) "Quantitative relationship between polarization differences and the zone averaged shift photocurrent" (PRB **96**, 075421 (2017)).
This paper says that "the integral of the shift vector over the BZ is proportional to the polarization difference between the conduction and valence bands" (Equation 9 of said paper)

However, I don't understand what this polarization of VB/CB means. From what I know, King-Smith and Vanderbilt's [modern theory of polarization](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.47.1651) in solids gives us polarization via integration of the Berry connection over the entire BZ, summed over all occupied bands. Following this definition, isn't this polarization a property of the material itself? Why is there a polarization of CBs/VBs specifically?

Any help on what this means physically, and/or any works reviewing this concept and providing equations on how to calculate these quantities is greatly appreciated.